# Sum elements across a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, sum, lapply, sapply

I have a list(Total) of 12 data.frames (all the same form) and I need the sum of every row of the list in colum 2.

I'm searching for a smarter way to sum the elements across the list like this:

```
Total[[1]][,2] + Total[[2]][,2] + Total[[3]][,2] +..+Total[[12]][,2]
```

colum 2 has a length of 70 so the result should be a vector of length 70

hope someone knows he right `sapply`, `lapply` or `apply` function code

Comment: Perhaps `Reduce("+", lapply(Total, "[[", 2))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I tought of that exact solution. Why don't you add it as an answer and you'll get an upvote from me.

Comment: If one of the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check-mark next to it. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
Reduce("+", lapply(Total, "[[", 2))
```

Note however, that this doesn't play well with potential NAs because of `+`.

Here's an example with built-in data:

```
Reduce("+", lapply(list(iris, iris, iris), "[[", 2))
```

Answer (score 7):

We can use `rowSums` after extracting the second column from the `list` of `data.frame`.  In case of any missing values, the `na.rm=TRUE` will take care of it.

```
rowSums(sapply(Total, `[[`, 2), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
Total %>%
      map(~.[[2]]) %>% 
      #or as suggested in the comments
      #map(2) %>%
      reduce(`+`)
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus I tried with your `list(iris, iris, iris)` and it is working fine for me

Comment: @docendodiscimus Okay, when I tested, I used the `[[`, but somehow, didn'tupdate it here. thanks

Comment: @akrun  for me, using `[` instead of `[[` resulted in an error as well

Comment: @Jaap Sorry, I was working on docendo's example but failed to update with 'Total' code

Comment: @Jaap and docendodiscimus, You guys are greate

Comment: One can simply use `map(2)` instead. Also note one is only using `purrr` here.